# How to convert string '4H6M' in minutes in PHP one liner?

Tags: php, date

How to convert `4H6M` in minutes ? I have tried `date()`, `strtotime()` and some other function but did not get desired result.

strtotime() returns false **

```
Input : 4H6M
Output: 246
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private function getDuration($duration=4H6M) {

    $result = array_combine(
        ['hour', 'minutes'],
        sscanf($duration, '%dH%dM')
    );

    return ($result['hour'] * 60) + $result['minutes'];
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

That's not a recognised date format, so the date functions aren't going to work without some manual parsing. Might as well just skip them completely:

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+)H([0-9])M/', '4H6M', $matches);
echo $matches[1] * 60 + $matches[2];
```

Comment: this function returns 0

Comment: It returns 246 - https://3v4l.org/2ej74